# Social Sharing Buttons in Recent Articles List

Tags: php, theme-development

I’m looking to add social sharing buttons for every post in a ‘Latest Articles’ category, using [tagDiv's Newspaper theme](http://forum.tagdiv.com/newspaper-theme-documentation/). I'm using the [Simple Share Buttons Adder](https://simplesharebuttons.com/), and it'll be nothing more than a simple call `echo do_shortcode('[ssba]');`, but I can't figure out where this list of articles is being populated in the homepage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I can add more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Had to download the theme files, and edit the module template used to populate the list, specifically the `td_module_10.php` template. Once modified, the files were sFTP-ed to the server, and everything worked as expected.